# Tkinter: get data from a Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am workin with Python 2.7. This is the initial part of a longer programme. What I want to do is to add a new username, together with is height and weight. I use a .txt file to store user data,

example `userlist3.txt`:

```
add_new_user 1 1

unknown_user 170 70

monthy 185 83

[empty line]
```

This is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
user_list = Tk()
user_list.title('Users')

def add_new_user():
    global select
    global height
    global weight 
    select = name.get()
    height = h.get()
    weight = w.get()   
    f = ' '
    us=open("userlist3.txt","a")
    print name, height, weight
    us.write(select + f + str(height) + f + str(weight) + "\n")
    us.close()
#    add_user.destroy() # it doesn't work
    user_list.destroy()

def onSelect(ev): # (10)
    global select
    select=listb.get(listb.curselection()) # (12)
    lab.configure(text=select) # (14)
    global name
    global h
    global w
    if select == 'add_new_user':
        add_user = Tk()
        add_user.title('New user')
        a=Label(add_user,text="Your username").pack()
        name = StringVar()
        NAME = Entry(add_user,textvariable = name).pack()
        b=Label(add_user,text="Your height (in cm)").pack()    
        h = IntVar()
        H = Entry(add_user,textvariable = h).pack()
        c=Label(add_user,text="Your weight (in kg)").pack()
        w = IntVar()
        W = Entry(add_user,textvariable = w).pack()
        Add_New_User=Button(add_user,text="Add new user data",command=add_new_user).pack()
        add_user.mainloop()
    else:
        user_list.destroy()

a=open("userlist3.txt","r")
b =[]
for linea in a:
    b.append(linea)
a.close()
e = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    e.append(b[i].split())
userlist = []
heightlist = []
weightlist = []
for i in range(len(e)):
    userlist.append(e[i][0])
    heightlist.append(e[i][1])
    weightlist.append(e[i][2]) 

sbar = Scrollbar(user_list, orient=VERTICAL) # (20)
listb = Listbox(user_list, width=30, height=4) # (22)
sbar.config(command=listb.yview) # (30)
listb.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set) # (32)
sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y) # (40)
listb.pack() # (42)
lab=Label(user_list,text="Double Click on User") # (50)
lab.pack()
for c in userlist: listb.insert(END,c)
listb.bind('<Double-1>',onSelect) # (70)
user_list.mainloop()

for d in range(1,len(userlist)):
    if userlist[d] == select:
        height = int(heightlist[d])
        weight = int(weightlist[d])

print "Selected user is: ",select
print height
print weight
```

It works with user already present in the txt file, but not if I want to add a new one. When I try, I got `'PY_VAR0 0 0'` printed on the shell and `'' 0 0` added in a new line in the txt file. Obviously these data are of no use in the following steps of my software.I'm probably missing a `.get()` somewhere.

Comment: some one said, it is not good to use two mainloops:
add_user = Toplevel(master) instead

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know this proverb, I'll bear it in mind :-D

Comment: @user2750495 Are you still stuck or did fixing the double mainloop solve you issue?

Comment: @Fiver: the solution metaphy wrote as a comment worked perfectly, but as it is not an answer I couldn't vote it! I did not try Bryan's one so far

Comment: @user2750495 Great, glad you got it sorted out. Keep in mind, you can always answer your own question and accept it. This will keep others from continuing to answer and help those seeking a solution for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Fiver for your advice!
metaphy's solution works, I solved the problem modifying line 28 in

add_user = Toplevel(user_list)

Answer (score 0):

When you see something like `PY_VAR0`, that means you are printing out the instance of a StringVar (or IntVar or whatever), rather than printing out the *value* of the variable. If you are using one of the special vars, you must call the `get()` method to get the value.

In your specific case, change this:

```
print name, width, height
```

To this:

```
print name.get(), width, height
```